# Split string by components and keep components in place

Tags: swift

Unlike `string.components(separatedBy: ...)` I want to keep the separators in place in the resulting array. Code is more explanatory

```
let input = "foo&bar|hello"
let output = string.tokenize(splitMarks: ["&", "|"])
let desiredResult = ["foo", "&", "bar", "|", "hello"]
```

Is there any function in the standard library which does this? If not how can I implement such a function?

Comment: I don't think there is a function that kept those components ... But you can loop through your array and append your component to your string

Comment: I'm no Regex jockey, but I'd dust off my Regex reference books for this one. Check out `NSRegularExpression`. Sometimes (just sometimes) it's the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that you need to loop through the `String` and check its each `characters` that is it tokens or not. You can make `extension` of `String` for that like this.

```
extension String {

    func stringTokens(splitMarks: Set<String>) -> [String] {

        var string = ""
        var desiredOutput = [String]()
        for ch in self.characters {
            if splitMarks.contains(String(ch)) {
                if !string.isEmpty {
                    desiredOutput.append(string)
                }
                desiredOutput.append(String(ch))
                string = ""
            }
            else {
                string += String(ch)
            }
        }
        if !string.isEmpty {
            desiredOutput.append(string)
        }
        return desiredOutput
    }
}
```

Now you can call this function like this way.

```
let input = "foo&bar|hello"
print(input.stringTokens(splitMarks: ["&", "|"]))
```

**Output**

```
["foo", "&", "bar", "|", "hello"]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using enumerated? I don’t see the index being used anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet, ...)` in a loop to
find the next occurrence of a split mark in the string, and then
append both the preceding part and the separator to an array:

```
extension String {

    func tokenize(splitMarks: String) -> [Substring] {

        let cs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: splitMarks)
        var result = [Substring]()
        var pos = startIndex
        while let range = rangeOfCharacter(from: cs, range: pos..<endIndex) {
            // Append string preceding the split mark:
            if range.lowerBound != pos {
                result.append(self[pos..<range.lowerBound])
            }
            // Append split mark:
            result.append(self[range])
            // Update position for next search:
            pos = range.upperBound
        }
        // Append string following the last split mark:
        if pos != endIndex {
            result.append(self[pos..<endIndex])
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let input = "foo&bar|hello"
let output = input.tokenize(splitMarks: "&|")
print(output)
// ["foo", "&", "bar", "|", "hello"]
```

Comment: Nice use of `rangeOfCharacter`.

Comment: For Swift 5+ you need to wrap the append parameters in a String slice.
result.append(String(self[pos..<range.lowerBound]))

Comment: @Brett: Yes, you are right. Or one changes the result type to `[Substring]`. That is a bit more efficient (avoids copies), and is also what the `split(separator:)` method returns. I have updated the code accordingly. Thanks for letting me know about the problem!

Comment: Thanks for the super quick update @MartinR, appreciate it mate.